# Unable to make an Image Blob JSON Serializable

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

JIRA Ticket created due to base64encode failure: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-5876

My Current CFG:
Titanium SDK 5.1.2.GA
Testing on an iPhone iOS 9.1

I'm stuck in a problem in a project for a client that requires images took on device (using the camera) to be sent to a WebService and afterwards be seen on any device using the app (both Android and iOS devices).
Titanium provides a Ti.Blob object (event.media) after taking a picture (which is not JSON serializable) and I need somehow to send this to the server. The server responds always a JSON object, thus this Blob must be somehow JSON serializable.

I've tried many ways without success:

1 - Base64Encode the Blob

```
var base64blob = Ti.Utils.base64encode(event.media);
```

Doesn't work, it stucks the app and throws a ASL exceeded maximum size error. I imagine that the image is too large to be base64encoded.

2 - Read the Blob into a Buffer

```
var blobStream = Ti.Stream.createStream({ source: event.media, mode: Ti.Stream.MODE_READ });
var buffer = Ti.createBuffer({ length: event.media.length });
var bytes = blobStream.read(buffer);
```

It works but I have no idea how can I transform this buffer holding the image contents into something that the server can return in a JSON object and later be transformed into an Image Blob again.

The server can't manage Ti.Blob objects or Ti.Buffer objects because, first of all, they are Titanium objects and the server is C# based, and second due to Ti.Blob and Ti.Buffer aren't JSON serializable, thus the JSON return doesn't work.

What I need is basically described in the imaginary example below:

```
var imageBlob = event.media;
var JSONSerializableImg = imageBlob.toJSON();
sendImageToServer(JSONSerializableImg);

var imgFromServer = getImageFromServer();
var imageBlob = imgFromServer.toBlob();
var imgView = createImageView({
    image: imageBlob 
});
```

I hope someone can help me with any conversion method possible.

Thank's

Comment: I do not know anything about Ti.BLOB. But BLOB should be binary large object. So, if you console write the BLOB, I would assume you get a binary string. You could: a) try to stuff that string into JS object: { blob: [BINARY] } and then use JSON.stringify(object) and send that to the server. On the server side, you can try and parse the binary and, if using SQL, push it into a BINARY(MAX) object or VARCHAR(MAX). Reverse the process to view. b) break the BLOB into several smaller arrays and push each individually with an order attached and reform it serverside, then store.

Comment: You say that "The server responds always a JSON object", but what does your server accept? Do you upload your image via eg. multipart upload? Or any other? Do you have any more information about your endpoint to which you are uploading the images?

Comment: @Rouse02 the Ti.Blob is an object which belongs to Titanium API (please, see this: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Blob). I can extract it's content into a Buffer and then decode this using Ti.Codec (please see this: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Buffer_and_Codec)
Do you think I can JSON.stringify something using this objects?
I know you don't know Titanium but maybe you taking a look at the documentation you can find out a solution.

Comment: @davidcyp The server only accepts generic objects used in any programming language but Titanium objects doesn't. I upload the images using HTTP POST requests, then the server responds a JSON object which is better for mobile applications. On the server side which is C# base the image is defined as "object" type, because Ti.Blob is a binary large object like Rouse02 wrote but still unknow. It is a Titanium API object and not a byte []  object for example.
Ideally should I transform the Titanium Blob or a Buffer into a string which would be JSON serializable.

Comment: Could you provide a full test case (`app.js` with code to take and then encode picture)? Then I could see if I can reproduce.

Comment: @FokkeZandbergen Try to just take a picture from the camera, it will return the photo as "event.media" on success event, which is a Ti.Blob object. Try to send this Blob to a server (doesn't matter how but send the data from image) and then retrieve it from server (getting a JSON as return, it is required) and show in an ImageView. The problem here is compatibility of technologies because other programming languages do not work with Titanium objects and Appcelerator doesn't provide proper conversions to standard data types. This simple problem is delaying the project 10 days so far, it's sad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by creating a separate method on server-side specially to upload photos. I followed the link below for server side:

[PHP code](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/titanium-mobile-build-an-image-uploader--mobile-8860)

In Titanium I had to set XHR's header like this:

`this.xhr.setRequestHeader("ContentType", "image/png");
this.xhr.setRequestHeader('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');`

That's it!
Thank's for all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

OK,

This is what I think you have to do. Looking at the API, this is very doable.

1: You need to create an object Server side that will hold the BLOB.

```
public class BlobContainer 
{
    public string fileName{get;set;}
    //... (Other properties)
    public byte[] data {get;set;}
}
```

2: Convert the important information from the BLOB into a binary array and send to server.

```
var blobStream = Ti.Stream.createStream({ source: myBlob, mode: Ti.Stream.MODE_READ });
var newBuffer = Ti.createBuffer({ length: myBlob.length });
var bytes = blobStream.read(newBuffer);
```

3: Then send the byte data to the server through Ajax requests. Be mindful of how big your array is that you are sending. It might be advantageous to split the array up and combine it on the other side (Might not be necessary):

```
var dataObjects: [
    { id: 1, data: [BYTE_DATA_PART] },
    { id: 2, data: [BYTE_DATA_PART] }...
]
$.each(dataObjects, function(i,a) {
    $.ajax({ url: "BLA", data: JSON.stringify(a), dataType: "json", type: "POST",
        success: function() { //CONTINUE\\ },
        error: function() {alert("ERROR BRO"}) 
    });
});
```

4: Then server side get each request in your little blob container, store in a session object or cache object and once you have N out of N, piece it all together and store that sucker in the Database.

5: Retrieve the stuff in the reverse order. Just remember that it is stored as byte[] data. You may have to fuddle with it and store it as a string because of the way the TI buffer creates bytes and the way c# interprets bytes. Best thing is trial and error. Once you have all the pieces back on the client.

```
var newBuffer = Ti.Stream.read(data, 0, data.length);
var newBlob = newBuffer.toBlob();
```

Comment: That's a possible solution, the problem is the step 2, the code you wrote just takes BLOB information into a Ti.Buffer(Titanium object). It still isn't a binary array. How can I extract this binary array so I can send to the server as you mentioned?

Comment: You use the var bytes = blobStream.read(newBuffer); This should take the buffer and return a byte array.

Comment: It doesn't, it just returns the number of bytes read.
Me and the guy responsible for the server are trying to find out something. Looking in the link below I discovered that a Ti.Buffer is capable to be accessed as a stantard array (buffer [0] for example), but it doesn't mean it is an array. That's the problem. http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Buffer_and_Codec
One important thing is, the buffer has approximately 9000000 of bytes. It is impossible for me on the mobile application side to loop this buffer and send it to the server. I tested here and it takes several minutes

Comment: So what we are trying to do is test out sending from mobile the Ti.Buffer or the Ti.Blob object to the server. On the server side declare the photo as generic "object" type because it is unknown in C#. After that, the server converts it to a standard byte [] object. And then serialize in base64 and send to mobile back. The problem is that this conversion of the photo on the server is not working properly. I send 9000000 of bytes and the server returns me 600 bytes back. Something is wrong on recognizing this generic "object" as a container of binary data that represents an image.

Answer (score 0):

To send and receive binary data to and from a server it's best to use [Ti.Network.HTTPClient](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient) which can send and receive binary data.

There's a guide on uploading and downloading files here:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/File_Uploads_and_Downloads

JSON [isn't designed](http://www.json.org/xml.html) to carry binary data, although base64encoded binary data should work. This is what `Ti.Utils.base64encode()` indeed is for. If you believe the "ASL exceeded maximum size error" you get shouldn't happen, please create a ticket on [Appcelerator JIRA](http://jira.appcelerator.org)

Comment: JIRA ticket included in my question.
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-5876

Answer (score -2):

I've used the following method before (not in Titanium, but another web-based mobile app platform).

```
function convertToDataURLviaCanvas(url, callback, outputFormat){
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var dataURL;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
        callback(dataURL);
        canvas = null; 
    };
    img.src = url;
}

convertToDataURLviaCanvas('http://example.com/image.png', function(base64Img){
    // Base64DataURL
});
```

I used this to send the base64 encoded image string as JSON to my backend server.  Then re-encoded the image on the server.  It worked for me, but the base64 encoded string is huge.

Comment: Does it work to binary data (blob) instead of URL's?
I do need to acquire the image from camera's device.

Comment: FYI, the code above won't work in a Titanium app. There's no DOM, no document, no Image object, and no Canvas.

Comment: That's right @ChrisBarber it won't work, but thank's Rossman66 for trying to help.

Comment: this is not true, there is a DOM, a document object and also image objects it you pipe this by an webview... i developed such a bridge some years ago; have a look into this again and its seems much easier today.