# Uploading image to presigned url using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

```
I am trying to upload a image to url using xmlhttprequest module in nodejs.For that I need to append fields to form data.




    const formData = new FormData();
    //op.data->presignedData
    Object.keys(op.data.fields).forEach(key => {
              formData.append(key, op.data.fields[key]);
     });
    formData.append("webmasterfile", b);//`b` is my file
    xhr.open("POST", op.data.url,true);
    error:
```

TypeError: source.on is not a function
            at Function.DelayedStream.create (D:\upload\node_modules\delayed-stream\lib\delayed_stream.js:33:10)

```
    //Reason :The keys that I am appending should be stringify but How to do it or any other method.


` const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       var content = '<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'; // the body of the new file...
       var b = new Blob([content], { type: "text/xml"});

       xhr.open('PUT', op.data.url);
       //sending file``
       xhr.send(b);`enter code here` `
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233932/unable-to-make-an-image-blob-json-serializable

Comment: Object.keys(op.data.fields).forEach(key => {
          formData.append(key, op.data.fields[key]);
 });-I am getting error at this not for file

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code.

```
var file=event.target.files[0]
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            progressCb(Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total));
        } else {
            progressUpdateCb(0)
        }
    }, false);
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function () {
        sucessCb()
    }, false);
    xhr.addEventListener('error', function () {
        errorCb()
    }, false);
    xhr.open('PUT', url);
    //sending file
    xhr.send(file);
```

For this method  you don't need to create form data. Just get the file object and upload it.

Comment: I want to uload with presigned data fiels into my header and then want to send.

Comment: Sorry. I Didn't understand. You want to upload a file aws s3 using presigned url, rigth?

Comment: Where is presignedData in your example(Are you directly passing url)?As it contains fields,url for authentication with s3

Comment: in reading the file object from jquery file change event. In your case read file object by any meassure and `xhr.open('PUT', url);` is the presigned url to which u r uploading and ` xhr.send(file);` is the filedata.

Comment: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "string" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer. Received type object
    at Function.byteLength (buffer.js:515:11)---getting this error

Comment: var content = '<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'; // the body of the new file...
       var b = new Blob([content], { type: "text/xml"});
       
       xhr.open('PUT', op.data.url);
       //sending file
       xhr.send(b);

Comment: Which front end framework are you using? react/angular/jquery?

Comment: I am reading a file from localsystem/creating one and sending it to s3 through nodejs